# Laravel displaying all posts with WHERE clause and pagenation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so i want to display post in my index page but only the posts that are reviewed by the admin. so i added another column in my database table post which is called "review" which is integer. So this is what i have in hand.

in my controller i have this

```
public function index()
    {

        $this->layout->content = View::make('partials.index', 
            array(
            'posts' => Post::paginate(9)
            ));
    }
```

and in my index page i have this

```
@section('content')
    <div class="dashboard">
    @foreach (array_chunk($posts->getCollection()->all(),2) as $row)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($row as $post)
                <article class="col-md-4 effect4" id="dash-box">
                    <p></p>

                    <c>{{$post->content}}</c><br>
                    <b>{{$post->title}}</b><br>
                    <d>posted..{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</d>
                    <hr>
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="page">
    {{$posts->appends(Request::only('difficulty'))->links()}}
    </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Help im newbie here i hope someone can help me out with this one hoping for a reply thanks

Comment: Clearly covered in the official Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/master/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call:

```
Post::whereReview(1)->paginate(9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) (and also the one for the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) since these pages apply to Eloquent as well)

You can just add a `where()` call to the query:

```
$posts = Post::where('review', '=', 1)->paginate(9);
```

Or a shorter version (`=` is the default operator)

```
$posts = Post::where('review', 1)->paginate(9);
```

Or even with a dynamic method name:

```
$posts = Post::whereReview(1)->paginate(9);
```

Also you can use `true` instead of `1`. Laravel will convert it:

```
$posts = Post::whereReview(true)->paginate(9);
```

---

There is also no need to do `chunking` that complicated:

```
@foreach (array_chunk($posts->getCollection()->all(),2) as $row)
```

You can just use the `chunk` method on any collection:

```
@foreach ($posts->chunk(2) as $row)
```

Comment: Thanks i already solved it                                                                                             $posts = Post::where('reviewed', '=' , 1);

  $this->layout->content = View::make('partials.index', array('posts' => $posts->paginate(9)));